# how to add the objects from main class to ArrayList in other class Java

Tags: java

I have this class which is supposed to have 3 lists of objects of other classes.
Now, how can I fill the list from the main class by using the following method
from the class?

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FcomCarRentalSystem {

    public List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    public List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    public List<Rental> rental = new ArrayList<Rental>();


    // Add Car
    public String addCar(Car tcar) {
        cars.add(tcar);
        String state =  "“added car successfully”";
        return state;
    }
```

Note that `Car`, `Customers`, `Rental` are classes and they have no problem.
Here is the main class. When I add the following car it is supposed to show the message "added successfully". But nothing shows in my main class.
What did I do wrong here?

```java
    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            FcomCarRentalSystem company = new FcomCarRentalSystem ();
             Car nii1 = new Car("QA33145","Nissan",CarType.SEDAN,true);
            company.addCar(nii1);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
You can see in these images what is required with the class diagram.

### --
[image]

[image]

Comment: You're not printing out the result of your operation

Comment: System.out.println(company.addCar(nii1); would help you see it.

Comment: just print the result you get and see !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FcomCarRentalSystem company = new FcomCarRentalSystem ();
    System.out.println(company.addCar(new Car()));
    System.out.println(company.addCustomer(new Customer()));
    System.out.println(company.addRental(new Rental()));
}
```